# Azure App Service Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-app-api

How do we access the App Settings in the Azure App Service using Azure backend Node.js?

Previously in Azure Mobile Services, we could use:

```
require('mobileservice-config');
```

But this is no longer valid.

Comment: Hi, any update now? is it helpful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a thread on MSDN in the same scenario with you, at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1052696e-f37a-4946-a833-5e3912ac3ab8/nodejs-get-app-settings?forum=azuremobile.

> Any settings or connection strings defined in the Azure portal or through environment settings are available on the `process.env` variable. Many of these are normalized into the mobile app configuration object (exposed through `req.azureMobile.configuration`), but if you've added any custom settings, use `process.env`.

E.G.

```
var appSettings = process.env
```